# I don't know how to use Role Theme Switcher

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, themes, roles

I installed Role Theme Switcher on my website but I didn't find any configuration menu in order to set my themes to roles! 
I don't know where is it??

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this helps anyone later.., Finally.. I found it under people menu,

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8.x:
Manage -> Configuration -> Systems -> Role theme